# Using a table made from input file Lua

Tags: input, lua, lua-table

I have a text file with contents like this

```
Jack 17
Will 16
Jordan 15
Elsie 16
```

You get the idea, it's a list of people's names with their ages.

I have a program that reads the file in. Like so:

```
file = io.open("ages.txt")
for line in file:lines() 
    do
        local name, age = line:match("(%a+) (%d+)")
        print(age) --Not exactly what I want
    end
file:close()
```

`print(age)` gives me the ages of all people, without names. It runs for everyone, as expected as it's within the loop (as an aside, why does it not work outside the loop? It gives me nil there)

What I want to do is load it into a table. This way, if I want to know Jack's age, I can go print(Jack.age) and it will give me 17. How can this be program be constructed to support this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this to build a table in the loop:

```
file = io.open("ages.txt")
names = {}

for line in file:lines() 
    do
        local n, a = line:match("(%a+) (%d+)")
        names[n] = {age = a}
    end
file:close()
```

Here is a sample interaction:

```
> print(names.Will.age)
16
> print(names.Jordan.age)
15
> print(names.Elsie.age)
16
```